# Merge video files with their original audio in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I need to merge two video files along with their corresponding audio.
I tried using :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

The videos gets merged, but their audio is missing. It's like a muted video. I need the audio also to be merged. I also googled on this, couldn't find anything useful. Can someone help me on this please...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Live-editing audio is exactly like live-editing video. Go back to each movie and fetch the audio track and stick it into your mutable composition.

In this example, I grab the first five seconds of video and the last five seconds of video from a movie and put them one after the other in a new video:

```
NSString* type = AVMediaTypeVideo;
NSArray* arr = [oldAsset tracksWithMediaType:type];
AVAssetTrack* track = [arr lastObject];
CMTime duration = track.timeRange.duration;
AVMutableComposition* comp = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVMutableCompositionTrack* comptrack = [comp addMutableTrackWithMediaType:type preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[comptrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)) ofTrack:track atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600) error:nil];
[comptrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeSubtract(duration, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)) ofTrack:track atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600) error:nil];
```

But the resulting video would be silent. So I also go back and fetch the corresponding audio:

```
type = AVMediaTypeAudio;
arr = [oldAsset tracksWithMediaType:type];
track = [arr lastObject];
comptrack = [comp addMutableTrackWithMediaType:type preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[comptrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)) ofTrack:track atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,600) error:nil];
[comptrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeSubtract(duration, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600)) ofTrack:track atTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5,600) error:nil];
```

Comment: 'AVMutableCompositionTrack *AudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];'
'[AudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];'

'AVMutableCompositionTrack *secondTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
// do same thing for another track , like this : **[secondTrack insertTimeRange:....**